# apple business manager federation username conflicts

Tags: apple-business

I want to enable federation in Apple Business Manager but there are conflicts as there are a lot of accounts already created with work email addresses. If we allow Apple Business Manager to reclaim these addresses will the enter user lose their text messages, phone contacts, etc.? I would prefer them not to create other apple id's as suggested by Apple Business Manager.